# hiding / showing of detailTextLabel in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, expand

I tried to hide my detailTextLabel.cell while my tableview loads,by the code,

```
cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[detailarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;
```

While selecting the row, try to display the detailarray in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, as expected the detailarray is displaying while am pressing the row and once i stop pressing it, the detailarray text disappears, why it is happening so,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSLog(@"indexpath is %d", indexPath.row);
selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
isSearching = YES;

[self.tableview beginUpdates];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text=[dealarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[detailarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;


[self.tableview endUpdates];



}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (isSearching && indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
{

    return 77;

}
return 44;


}
```

EDITED:

Assigned a variable 'a' in .h file and used the code as follows,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text=[dealarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[detailarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"dealarray %@\n %@",dealarray,detailarray);

    if (a==-1) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;

    }
    else if(a==indexPath.row)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;
               }
    else cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;

return cell;


}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSLog(@"indexpath is %d", indexPath.row);
selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
isSearching = YES;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text=[dealarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[detailarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
a=indexPath.row;
[tableview reloadData];
```

}

Comment: Do you need to show detailLabelText appearing after pressing also???

Comment: @NeelamVerma, ya i need to show detailLabelText only after its pressed, because i expect to show the detailed explanation about the selected row.

Answer (score 2):

For this, You can use two type of cell.

For normal data, use basic cell. On selection, reload table or cell and use another detailLabel cell for selected row only.

And it will solve your issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your requirement, Can you try below code to resolve your purpose.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /* .

     Write necessary code here....
     */

    // -------------
    cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (![selectedRowIndexs containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]])
    {
         cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;

    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;

    }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[detailarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;
    if (![selectedRowIndexs containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [selectedRowIndexs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }

}
```